# Whenever I refresh the page a method is being called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have an issue with a button on ruby on rails version 4. It seems as if every time I refresh a page the method update_likes is being called when I only call it what I click a button. Here is my code for the button on the model

```
%p 
  %b Likes:
  = @item.likes   
  = link_to "Like", :onclick => @item.update_likes
```

and here is the method its calling (update_likes) from the controller

```
  def update_likes
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.update_likes 
  end
```

If I eliminate the :onclick => @item.update_likes nothing happens when i refresh the page but once I add it it calls the method on click and on refresh.

Can anyone see my problem?

Any suggestions would be helpful! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

onclick is used for trigger javascript functions, but here you dont have javascript function but a simple call which is going to be triggered whenever page will be rendered, so you need to update your code like this

```
= link_to "Like", :onclick => "some_javascript_function_to_call_update_likes_on_server(#{@item.id})"
```